# JavaFx Repaint Canvas on StyleCssClass Change

Tags: css, javafx, stylesheet, scene

To change the stylesheet to a dark one in my code I execute in Scene :

```
 getStylesheets().add(FxFrame.class.getResource("/css/dark.css").toExternalForm())
```

This works fine. 
I also have a canvas where some colors are configured using:

```
final StyleablePropertyFactory<FxDrawCanvas> FACTORY = new StyleablePropertyFactory<FxDrawCanvas>(FxDrawCanvas.getClassCssMetaData());
StyleableProperty<Color> calloutBackground1Color = FACTORY.createStyleableColorProperty(FxDrawCanvas.this, "callout-background1-color", "callout-background1-color", s -> s.calloutBackground1Color, Color.web("0xffffff" ));
```

The canvas should be repainted when the stylesheet css gets changed. How may I make the canvas aware of scene css change ? 
Is possible to listen on css stylesheet changes in the canvas ? 
Or fire any event in the scene which the canvas can intercept ?

Comment: Is the `CssMetaData` object corresponding to this property returned from `FxDrawCanvas.getCssMetaData`? JavaFX should update the value automatically if a new stylesheet contains a rule with a higher percedence than the current way of assigning the property value (or if the value is unassigned).

Comment: The value is updated correctly. What I miss is to repaint the canvas. I have to do this, but I don't know when the stylableProperty changed.

Comment: Add a listener to `calloutBackground1Color`.

Comment: Since `syleClass`, `styleSheet` and `style` are `ObservableValue`s you can listen to their changes as you want. I don't really understand what the problem is.

Comment: Right, I can listen on the styleSheet property. But this is somewhere in the Scene. My component is much more down, inside other class. I would search to a way to listen to some property on my node if possible. I tried to listen on calloutBackgrounColor but is not possible, and I didn't found any other property I can listen on.

Comment: as others already said: the canvas will repaint itself given the background is a styleable property that's implemented to call a requestLayout) or any other means that repaints everything) on its invalidated. If that doesn't happen in your case, please provide a mcve as outlined in http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: hmm ... just tested with a custom styleableProperty in TableColumn: it's simply working, without any additional listener. Leaving no way but a mcve provided by you: could be either in your code or somehow special to canvas or a bug ...